# How to show/hide ribbon and quick launch in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm building a site using Sharepoint 2010 but unfortunately i have very limited options as far as server side editing (my workplace deleted a few features from the sharepoint server).

Right now i'm displaying different Lists in tabs (using EasyTabs 5.0 script) and for this i need to show the lists without any UI - no ribbon and no quick launch.
I found a way to get rid of both but now i find myself in a new predicament - i can't edit the list using the ribbon because i don't know how to bring it back!

to hide the ribbon and/or i used content editor parts with the following code:

```
<style type="text/css"> 

#s4-ribbonrow, .ms-cui-topBar2, .s4-notdlg, .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .s4-notdlg noindex, #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, #s4-titlerow, #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, #s4-leftpanel-content {display:none !important;}
    .s4-ca{margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;}


</style>
```

Any ideas on how to edit my list now or maybe how to get the ribbon back?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - you should use scripts to do this - that way you can add a web part to execute the proper CSS when you need it.

The VERY best way to do this is to use a text file to store the CSS (or script). Add to a document library then use a content editor web part to execute it.

For example, to hide the left navigation (all sites):

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-leftpanel { display:none !important; }
.s4-ca { margin-left:0px !important; }
</style>
```

To show the left navigation in a publishing site:

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-leftpanel{
width:155px;
float:left;
display:inline !important;
}
.s4-ca{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background:#fff;
margin-left:155px !important;
margin-right:0px;
min-height:324px;
}
</style>
```

Using this method you don't have to embed things - and you can add the web parts to a page layout automatically.

David Sterling
davidmsterling.blogspot.com
www.sterling-consulting.com

Answer (score 1):

Never mind , got it. you can just edit the page using the sharepoint designer- there you can see the hidden web part with the CSS code and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Content Editor Web Part without resorting to SharePoint designer, you just use the Web Part Page Maintenance page. Example, if your page is

```
http://stackoverflow.com/SitePages/NoRibbon.aspx
```

simply change it to

```
http://stackoverflow.com/SitePages/NoRibbon.aspx?Contents=1
```

From the Web Part Page Maintenance page, check the Content Editor Web Part and click "Delete". Now, you will lose the code you put in the Content Editor Web Part, but you will have your page back. I always copy and paste from NotePad or SP Designer when working with CSS and JavaScript in case I have to blow away the CEWP like this.